# How WCS returns GML to Client?

Tags: geoserver, gml

I have searched many information in Internet but don't know for example how to implement a WCS service like GeoServer. I suppose they a Geo Sever need to use some (GML Schema like version GML 3.2.1 to generate geodetic data to Web Client that can be a GIS application).

So question is the relation between GML Schema (a kind of template) plus some data object to GML returns to Web Client, how to implement? (I just want to ask general idea no need to detail).

Comment: As far as I know GeoServer WCS can't create coverages encoded as GML. Perhaps Rasdaman can. But perhaps your use case is more like Web Feature Service (WFS) with application schema http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/app-schema/index.html.

Comment: Good work, I want to know how to create encoded as GML. Thanks.